# Error: calling delete twice on the same memory location

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator

I wrote this function in C++ as part of a bigger program:

```
Object Single_list<Object>::pop_front() {
    //Single_node<Object> *tmp_front;  
    //Object hold;
    if (empty()) {
        throw underflow();
    } 

    Single_node<Object> first_node = front();
    Single_node<Object> *ptr = list_head;                                                            
    list_head = list_head->next();  
    delete ptr;
    return first_node.retrieve();
}
```

However, when I try and use this function I get the following message:

> WARNING: calling delete twice on the same memory location: 0x100100160

I am really confused, I am not deleting the pointer (assuming that's what is causing the problem?) twice.

Any advice will be appreciated.

As requested, here is the constructor and retrieve function for the Single_Node, although I am not sure how helpful this will be to the error regarding deletion that I am getting:

```
template <typename Object>
Single_node<Object>::Single_node( const Object &e, Single_node<Object> *n ):element( e ), next_node( n )
{
    // empty constructor
}

template <typename Object>
Object Single_node<Object>::retrieve() const
{
    return element;
}

template <typename Object>
Single_node<Object> *Single_node<Object>::next() const
{ 
    return next_node;
}
```

Comment: If this is really the only relevant code, then the compiler is wrong. It can be wrong sometimes.

Comment: Please post some complete code that shows the problem

Comment: From the code shown the problem seems to be that you are returning the object stored by first_node after deleting it (assuming list_head and front() return the same thing). It's hard to tell without knowing the semantics of Single_node though.

Comment: That can't be a compiler error..

Comment: It's not an error, its a warning.

Comment: @Mankarse: The `first_node = front()` makes a copy.  The copy might not be deep enough, however.

Comment: Not a compile time warning though--it specifies the address of the double delete. I'm guessing this an exception thrown by this library: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Projects/src/ece250.h. It's the only thing that came up on google when I searched the warning text

Comment: It's all guesswork with the information we have. Your best bet is to hook up a debugger with some instrumentation to get the stack of the initial delete (for windows, use gflags to enable usermode stack trace)

Comment: I bet the error is somewhere else. I am betting you are violating the rule of three. Either Object or Simple_node. Can you paste the class definitions to these class definitions.

Comment: I noticed something, Single_node<Object> *tmp_front; is stored on stack. Delete operator is only meant for data in the heap because that needs explicit deletion. Data on stack is deleted at the end of the program execution. Thus I took out the delete tmp_front and I am no longer getting the error. Seeing as I do not get the error message I am hoping this was the source of the problem and that my explanation is correct....

Comment: How do you add nodes to the list?

Comment: @rr: A few points: first, the *pointer* is stored on the stack, not the pointed-to block, which had better exist either on the heap or as a global. Second, data on the stack is destructed *at the end of its enclosing block,* not necessarily the end of the program. Finally, debugging by hope is a really bad idea. If you're reduced to hoping, then you need to refactor.

Comment: @Alan Stokes : I add a node by creating an instance of the SingleNode class. For instance for the push_back function I have to insert a node at the back of the list so I do `Single_node<Object> *tmp_back;
 tmp_back = new Single_node<Object>(obj, NULL);` Please refer to the SingleNode constructor code given in my question for more details on that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Mankarse's comment, try the following:

```
Object Single_list<Object>::pop_front() {

    if (empty()) {
        throw underflow();
    } 

    Object result = front().retrieve();

    Single_node<Object> *ptr = list_head;
    list_head = list_head->next();  
    delete ptr;
    return result;
}
```

This grabs the result from the first node before it gets deleted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I already store the nodes content in the hold variable and then I return this hold variable. So, deleting the node should have no affect on the return value...

Comment: @rr - Does `Single_node` have a destructor? What does that do?

Comment: @rr: You're sure that `=` performs a deep copy? And I really have to wonder what `Object` is; if you store it in `Single_node` be value instead of reference, then `Object` can't be polymorphic... and the name implies that it is.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: Object can be anything because its a template `type:template <typename Object>
Object Single_list<Object>::pop_front()....`

Comment: @Bo Persson : Single_node does not have a destructor but SingleList does, where I just do pop_front while the list is not empty. `while (!empty()){
  pop_front();
 }
 `

Comment: @Mike DeSimone:  There are three places in my question's code where = is used. I am assuming you are referring to this line  `list_head = list_head->next();  ` --- The next() function is in the Single_node class and simply returns the next_node variable whose value is assigned in the constructor as the value is passed when an instance of the Single_node class is created. Based on all this, I don't see how a shallow copy problem could arise. Please let me know if you agree.

Comment: No, I meant `first_node = front();` which is where you grab the value for eventual return. That makes me think of two possible problems, depending on `Object`'s type: if `Object` is a pointer, then whatever pops a node is responsible for deleting the pointed-to value, and if `Object` is a type with a destructor that deletes internal storage, then `delete ptr;` calls the destructor and deletes the storage, leading to an `Object` returned which seems valid externally but has a wild pointer in it, and then deletion of that `Object` double-deletes the `Object`'s internal storage.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: thanks for all your help. In sum, the reason for my error was that I was freeing memory which was not dynamically allocated.